# authentication failure between 2 ec2 instances with windows server 2016

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, automationanywhere

I am a newbie to AWS Cloud. Recently I was given the requirement to do a Automation Anywhere Clustered Control Room installation on AWS Cloud. Based on this requirement, I set up 2 EC2 instances (as a test run) with Windows Server 2016 AMI. I installed MS SQL server on one of the instances and opened port 1433 for access from the other instance. I installed Control Room on the first instance successfully (using custom install). When I completed the installation on the second instance, I got credential vault error. I have created a shared folder which is accessible by both the instances inspite of which I am getting the error. I have security groups and firewalls setup appropriately alsoI have shared the snapshot below. I have been informed that there is an authentication issue between the 2 instances. How do I get this to work?

[image]

Any and all help is much appreciated.

I don't know if this is a duplicate of any other question. If it is, please point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve the problem. I reinstalled the control room on both the EC2 machines with Manual mode for the Credential Vault access.

I also reset the firewall to allow only 80 and 443 (for now) both locally and remotely on the second EC2 instance.